# All GoogleVision label possibilities?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I'm searching for a list of all the possible image labels that the Google Cloud Vision API can return?
I believe they used the same labels the following project: https://github.com/openimages/dataset

I thought of two possible methods of getting these labels:

1. Sending thousands of different images to the API and recording the returned labels (I would automate this)
2. Going through all the Google Open Image data (which I linked above), and recording the labels.

I'm not sure how I could do option 2, and was hoping that someone had already done one of these options.
Please let me know if there already exists a list like the one I am describing, or there is a better method of obtaining it (than the two which I thought of).

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the repository you've provided there is a class-descriptions.csv file which is a list of all possible 19868 labels. This seems to be what you're looking for?

However there is **no guarantee** that this list is the same as the vision API!

Comment: are you referring to this file? https://github.com/openimages/dataset/blob/master/dict.csv

Comment: I was talking about the Classes and class descriptions (293 KB) file: 
https://storage.googleapis.com/openimages/2017_07/classes_2017_07.tar.gz